# loadDataWithBaseURL not work on android jelly bean

Tags: android, android-webview

This code does not work on Android 4.1.2 but works on Android 2.3.6. In teste.js file I put a javascript alert.

The alert isn't showing in 4.1.2 but show in 2.3.6, apparently the javascript is not loading:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", 
"<html><head><script type='text/javascript' src='teste.js' /></head><body></body>"
+ "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You should provide more information about what exactly does not work with the code you posted.  Do you simply not see the javascript alert?  Are there any errors you see?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your instruction. I don't see javascript alert on android 4.1.2 but see on android 2.3.6.